# f:ajax works only with @form or @all

Tags: ajax, jsf, composite-component

i have a composite component that contains a form with ajax. what i can't figure out is why it only works for the @form/@all render parameter.

```
    <cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="radioItem"/>
    <cc:attribute name="radioItems" />
    <cc:attribute name="compImage" />
    <cc:attribute name="compSpecification"/>

    </cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <h:form> 
        <div id="options">
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{cc.attrs.radioItem}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.radioItems}" />
                <f:ajax render=":details" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
        </div>

        <div id="details">
            <h:graphicImage value="#{cc.attrs.compImage}"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.compSpecification}"/>
        </div>      
   </h:form> 
</cc:implementation>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is two-fold:

1. You're specifying an absolute client ID `:details` while the element to be re-rendered is inside the **same** `UINamingContainer` parent, so JSF won't be able to locate it in the component tree. You need to specify a relative client ID `details`.
2. You have specified the ID on a plain vanilla HTML element instead of a real JSF component, so JSF won't be able to locate it in the component tree. You need to use a real JSF component. You need to replace `<div>` by `<h:panelGroup layout="block">`.

So, fix it both:

```
<h:form> 
    <div id="options">
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{cc.attrs.radioItem}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.radioItems}" />
            <f:ajax render="details" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </div>

    <h:panelGroup id="details" layout="block">
        <h:graphicImage value="#{cc.attrs.compImage}"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.compSpecification}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>      
</h:form>
```

That it works with `@form` and `@all` is just because JSF can locate the element to be re-rendered relative to the component on which the ajax action is been invoked, namely the parent `UIForm` and `UIViewRoot` component respectively.